# Changing innerHTML text according to active ID bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have something like this

```
<p id="step-number">1</p>
```

And tabs like this

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="step-1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
1
</div>
<div id="step-2" class="tab-pane fade">
2
</div>
<div id="step-3" class="tab-pane fade">
3
</div>
</div>

 <a href="#step-1" data-toggle="tab">STEP 1</a> 
 <a href="#step-2" data-toggle="tab">STEP 2</a> 
 <a href="#step-3" data-toggle="tab">STEP 3</a>
```

What i need is to change p text to active div id?
It means when step-1 is active to write 1, and when step-2 active to write 2 etc.

Here is working fiddle?
http://www.bootply.com/uSba2geIru

Is it possible to do that in bootstrap 3 or in jquery?

Comment: in which event a div will get activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('#step-number').text($(e.target).text());
});
```

More On:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
   $('#step-number').text($.trim($($(e.target)[0].hash).html()));
});
```

Comment: Nice clean and simple solution

Comment: Only one problem its get text in element, is it possible to get element href, like not to write STEP 1, to write that element href, and to echo #step-1, because in that txt will be like NEXT txt

Comment: I think ur talking about this: `$('#step-number').text($.trim($($(e.target)[0].hash).attr('id')));`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    $('#step-number').text($(e.target).text());
});
```

[More about tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage)